# Макрос. Замена данных в word

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

Excel макрос открывает word файл и выполняет там замену.
Все работает корректно за исключением случаев, когда Длина(ЗначениеКлюча) больше 400 символов.
В этом случае появляется ошибка:
"Run-time error '5854'
 Слишком длинный строковый параметр".

```
 With WD.Range.Find
  .Text = НазваниеКлюча
  .Replacement.Text = ЗначениеКлюча
  .Forward = True
  .Wrap = 1
  .Format = False: .MatchCase = False
  .MatchWholeWord = False
  .MatchWildcards = False
  .MatchSoundsLike = False
  .MatchAllWordForms = False
  .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
 End With
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста.

Comment: какой параметр?

Comment: *Слишком длинный строковый параметр* — так сократите его!